# Best practice for dependency injection in an AngularJS service with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-service

I find dependency injection for AngularJS services in TypeScript to be somewhat cumbersome.   Currently, I define a factory method inside my service class, and have to repeat all dependency injection arguments three times:

```
class MyService {
    public static Factory($rootScope, myController) {       // 1st time
        return new MyService($rootScope, myController);     // 2nd time
    }
    constructor(public $rootScope, public myController) {}  // 3rd time
}
myModule.factory('myService', MyService.Factory);
```

I would like to do the following, but that does not seem to work:

```
class MyService {
    constructor(public $rootScope, public myController) {}  // only once
}
myModule.factory('myService', MyService);
```

This approach works fine for controllers, but not so for services. Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use angular's injector to create your controller instead of having a factory method.

Here is a sample in typescript

```
/// <reference path='d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts' />

class MyCtrl {
  public phrase: string;
  constructor($window) {
    this.phrase = 'I was loaded by injector';
  }

  speak() {
    alert(this.phrase);
  }
}

function main() {
  var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  var ctrl = injector.instantiate(MyCtrl);
  ctrl.speak();
}
```

And a fiddler to prove it works: http://jsfiddle.net/UPv5j/3/

Answer (score 6):

You should user `service` not `factory` :

```
class MyService {
    constructor(public $rootScope) {}  // only once
}
myModule.service('myService', MyService);
```

Comment: Also note that 'myModule.service('myService', MyService);' must go *after* class declaration. Placing it before will make code compiling but causing errors in runtime (something like accessing prototype on undefined).